# Apply/lapply function to all columns in matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix, apply, lapply

I have a matrix called **seq$num**, consisting of 100 columns and 30k rows. Each column corresponds to the name of a specific sample (es. CAGTCA), and every row is about a numeric value. With this type of object, I can access the first row writing seq$num[[1]] and so on for the other rows. This is a brief example of my database:

| CAGTCA | AGATCA | GCTCGA | GCTCGA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -0.4930 | -2.0330 | 0.7100 | 0.1560 |
| 1.0030 | 0.0120 | -1.0433 | 0.6701 |
| 0.0013 | 1.0013 | 1.2451 | -1.3421 |

I would like to loop through all the samples using the **lapply** function and for each sample classify:

- the numbers above 1.5 as "high".
- the numbers below 0 as "low".
- the numbers between 0 and 1.5 as "medium".

Then I need also to take note of how many high, low and medium numbers have a sample.

How can this be done? I've tried applying the lapply function, but I don't get the output I want.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function which divides data into categories.

```
classify <- function(x) ifelse(x >= 1.5, 'high', ifelse(x < 0, 'low', 'medium'))
```

For each dataframe in `seq$num` apply the `classify` function to it and use `table` to count.

```
res <- lapply(seq$num, function(x) table(classify(as.matrix(x))))
```